# Getting route name in laravel 4.2 in all views

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i have this route defined in my routes file ::

```
Route::get('user/dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'AdminController@index']);
```

and i am trying to read the name of the route, in this case 'dashboard', in all my views, already i know how to pass that using the view::share() method. 
I have checked everywhere online, and looking through the laravel API, i have seen several methods two of which are,

```
//1. Route::currentRouteName();
//2. Route::getName();
```

but none of them seems to be working, please what am i doing wrong and what is the best way to get the name string...

regards.

Comment: The `Route::currentRouteName()` should do it, how is it not working? Is it coming through as `null` or is something else happening?

Comment: i've tried that and its giving me a blank screen, dont know why... i am still debugging hoping it would work soon.

Comment: i tried this :: echo ' the name is = ' . Route::currentRouteName(); but what i got was ' the name is = ', and the second part Route::currentRouteName() did not display...

Answer (score 1):

The `Request class` provides many methods for examining the HTTP request for your application and extends the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request class`

Write `Request::path()` to get current URI.

Check this [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

Comment: okay, thanks, let me try this option, since i was trying to use the switch statement based on the string value of the name. i hope this works.